# proving the conjugate transpose of a linear map is the adjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $(V,g)$ be a finite dim. inner product space and let $B$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$ Let $T:V \to V$ be Linear.

show $[T^*]_B = \overline{ [T]^T_B }$

my attempt: from the given information I have deduced that:

$\overline{g(Tv,v)} = \overline{g(v,T^{\ast}v)} = g(T^{\ast}v,v)$ which implies that:
$\overline{[v]_B^T[T]_B^T[v]_B} = [v]_B^T[T^*]_B^T[v]_B$ but I'm not sure how to conclude from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that the adjoint is defined by
$$g(Tv, w) = g(v, T^\ast w) \qquad \forall v,w\in V$$
So we must verify that
$$g(Tv, w) = g(v, \left[\overline{[T]_B^T}\right]_V w) \qquad\forall v,w\in V$$
Where I invent $[T]_V$ to mean the map $\tilde T$ such that $[\tilde T]_B = T$
Or in base $B$
$$[v]_B^\ast [T]_B [w]_B = \overline{[w]_B^\ast \overline{[T]_B^T} [v]_B} \qquad \forall v,w\in V$$
Where $v^\ast = \overline{v^T}$ by definition.

Comment: How did you get $v^* = \overline{v^T}$ I've never seen that definition

Comment: What does $T^T$ mean?

Comment: @Jason8762 The inner product in a base $B$ satisfies
$$g(v, w) = \overline{[v]_B^T} [w]_B$$

Comment: @copper.hat The transpose of the representation matrix.

Comment: I understand what transpose means for a matrix, but not for an operator $T:V \to V$.

Comment: @copper.hat Clear now?

Comment: @AlexR $g(v,w) = [v]_B^T[w]_B$ in my textbook

Comment: No. $T:V \to V$ is an operator. You can define the transpose for the matrix representation, but it is meaningless for $T$ unless you provide some structure on $V$ (which is what the matrix representation does).

Comment: @Jason8762 This is not going to work for complex vector spaces, unfortunately.

Comment: @copper.hat I now defined $[\cdot]_V$ to be the inverse of $[\cdot]_B$ to clearly separate operators from representation matrices. Did you see that? Are you okay now?

Comment: I'm fine :-). ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Glad to hear that :'D Your nitpicking is justified in this context, so thanks for helping me make this answer as correct as possible :)

Comment: @AlexR Could you give a little more information, why owuld it not work for complex vector spaces?

Comment: @Jason8762 Confer the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition). For $\mathbb C^n$ the standard inner product is
$$\langle x, y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar x_i y_i = \overline{x^T}y$$
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors) as well

Comment: @Jason8762 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F} $ be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let $B=(b_1,...,b_n)$ be the orthonormal basis for $V$.

For any $v$ we have $v = \sum_k g(v, b_k) b_k$.

The defining characteristic of $T^*$ is $g(Tv,w) = g(v,T^*w)$.

The operator $[\cdot]_B : V \to \mathbb{F}^n$ is defined by $[b_k]_B = e_k$, so if
$x=\sum_k x_k b_k$, then $[x]_B = \sum_k x_k e_k$. The inverse of this operator is given by $[\cdot]_B^{-1}:\mathbb{F}^n \to V$, and is easily checked to be
$[\cdot]_B^{-1}(\sum_k x_k e_k) = \sum_k x_k b_k$. Given an operator $L:V \to V$, we define the operator $[L]_B :\mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^n $ by
$[L]_B = [\cdot]_B \circ L \circ [\cdot]_B^{-1}  $.

If $A: \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^n $, the $ij$ component is given by $[A]_{ij} = e_i^T A e_j$.

If $L :V \to V $, then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
e_i^T [L]_B e_j &=& e_i^T [L b_j]_B \\
&=& e_i^T [\sum_k g(L b_j, b_k) b_k]_B \\
&=& e_i^T \sum_k g(L b_j, b_k) [b_k]_B \\
&=& e_i^T \sum_k g(L b_j, b_k) e_k \\
&=& \sum_k g(L b_j, b_k) e_i^T e_k \\
&=& g(L b_j, b_i)
\end{eqnarray}
And finally:
$e_i^T [T]_B e_j = e_j^T [T]_B^T e_i = g(T b_j, b_i) = g(b_j , T^* b_i) = \overline{g(T^* b_i, b_j)} = \overline{ e_j^T [ T^*]_B e_i } = e_j^T \overline{  [ T^*]_B }  e_i$.